# Installing Landscape and launch the OpenStack Autopilot

Tags: maas, cloud, openstack, landscape, openstack-autopilot

Try [Installing The Canonical Distribution of Ubuntu Open Stack](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-ubuntu-openstack) but stuck on step 4. Setup *Landscape* and launch the *OpenStack Autopilot*, it always fails.  Attached is the output of `~/.cloud-install/commands.log`

I was only able to get this far after running on the *MaaS* host

```
sudo apt-get install juju-core juju-local
```

Was this a mistake?

Looking at the host that is used, this is the output after `openstack-install` fails,  along with output of ~`/.cloud-install/commands.log`:

- [1st attempt](http://pastebin.com/H5GxGNpb)
- [2nd attempt](http://pastebin.com/yH3eZ8kW)
- [running node](http://pastebin.com/qBtgRVCn)

Like all nodes in *MaaS*, they are e3-12xx 16GB RAM, Two 1TB disks and Two NIC with IPMI, MaaS is able to control their power, all are set to PXE boot, with all other options disabled

Answer (score 1):

From your 2nd attempt paste, looks like you hit https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju-core/+bug/1425435. Can you try upgrading your python-jujuclient package to the version in this PPA and see if it fixes your problem?

https://launchpad.net/~ahasenack/+archive/ubuntu/python-jujuclient